# Change data range of Chart in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint-2010

I have an Excel file that contains data and charts. I've created a macro to read in a text file and update the data and the chart data ranges based on the date in the excel file. The data range will be starting 5 day prior to the date in the text file up to the date.

This works perfectly in Excel but now what I would like the macro to do is open a PowerPoint file I've already created that contains the two charts linked to the Excel file and change the data range of the Excel chart in the PowerPoint presentation.

I am able to open the PowerPoint and select the graph by name but I cannot change the data range.

Here is the code I am using currently that is not working but also not throwing any errors...

Open the PowerPoint and set the global oPPT variable to the open presentation.

```
Public Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()
'Opens a PowerPoint Document from Excel

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Set oPPTFile = objPPT.Presentations.Open(FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DailyHealthCheck.pptx")
End Sub
```

Call the routine above, change dates on some labels, and then attempt to change the source data of the Excel.

```
' open the gd metrics power point, must be manually closed later
Open_PowerPoint_Presentation

' set the dates in the ppt slide to the current date
oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Low Left Date").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "MMMM d, yyyy")
oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Critical Issues Table").Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Grid Director Critical Issues (as of " & Format(Now, "M/d") & ")"

' change the date ranges of the chart
If ppdRangeStr <> "" Then
    Dim splitDateRange() As String
    splitDateRange = Split(ppdRangeStr, ":")
    ppdRangeStr = "='process per day'!$" & Left(splitDateRange(0), 1) & "$" & Right(splitDateRange(0), Len(splitDateRange(0)) - 1) & ":$" & Left(splitDateRange(1), 1) & "$" & Right(splitDateRange(1), Len(splitDateRange(1)) - 1)
    MsgBox ppdRangeStr
    oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Processed Per Day Chart").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ppdRangeStr, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ' reset data labels

    oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Processed Per Day Chart").LinkFormat.Update

End If
```

The String ppdRangeStr is "'processed per day'!$H77:$G81" which is the same range the chart in the Excel file (which works) is using.

Does anyone know how I can make the macro in the Excel file change the source data of the Excel chart in the PowerPoint where the source data is in the Excel file? (If that make sense?)

Comment: If the chart in PowerPoint is a linked chart to the Excel chart, you must change the SourceData of the Excel chart and then update the LinkFormat of the linked chart in PowerPoint.

Comment: I've updated the LinkFormat of the chart but it does not update the range.

Comment: What is the difference between the Paste option 'Use Destination Theme and Link Data (L)' and Paste Special->Paste Link? The 'Paste Link' option will update the chart with out vba but distorts the text when I resize the chart in PowerPoint.

Comment: If only the chart's data is linked to Excel, then put a `oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Processed Per Day Chart").Chart.ChartData.Activate` before the `oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes("Processed Per Day Chart").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ppdRangeStr, PlotBy:=xlColumns`.